# Reading the g:datePicker-value in Grails without using the "new Object(params)"-method

Tags: grails, datepicker, gsp, taglib

Let's say I have a datePicker called "foobar":

```
<g:datePicker name="foobar" value="${new Date()}" precision="day" />
```

How do I read the submitted value of this date-picker?

One way which works but has some unwanted side-effects is the following:

```
def newObject = new SomeClassName(params)
println "value=" + newObject.foobar
```

This way of doing it reads all submitted fields into newObject which is something I want to avoid. I'm only interested in the value of the "foobar" field.

The way I originally assumed this could be done was:

```
def newObject = new SomeClassName()
newObject.foobar = params["foobar"]
```

But Grails does not seem to automatically do the translation of the foobar field into a Date() object.

**Updated:** Additional information can be found in the [Grails JIRA](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-3740).

Comment: Is field foobar on SomeClassName a Date type?

Using def might not force the coersion, wheras a declared type could force the binding to coerce type. 

Haven't faced this before, more wondering....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the g:datePicker value became a lot easier in Grails 1.2 (see [release notes](http://www.grails.org/1.2+Release+Notes)):

> **Better Date parsing**
>
> If you submit a date from a
>    tag,
>   obtaining the Date object is now as
>   simple as looking it up from the
>   params object by name (eg. params.foo
>   )

Answer (score 4):

Use the [command object](http://grails.org/Command+objects+and+Form+Validation) idiom.  In the case of your example, I will assume that your form calls the action `handleDate`. Inside the controller:

```
def handleDate = { FoobarDateCommand dateCommand ->
    def theNextDay = dateCommand.foobar + 1
}
```

Here's `FoobarDateCommand`.  Notice how you name the field the same as in the view:

```
class FoobarDateCommand { 
    Date foobar 
}
```

Command objects are a handy way to encapsulate all validation tasks for each of your forms, keeping your controllers nice and small.

Answer (score 0):

When a param says to be a "struct", this means there are a number of params to represent its value. In your case, there are:

- params["foobar_year" storing year
- params["foobar_month"] storing month
- params["foobar_day"] storing day

Just fetch them out and do whatever you want :)

Answer (score -2):

You still need to know the format though

```
def newObject = new SomeClassName()
newObject.foobar = Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', params.foobar)
```

Comment: The value of params.foobar is the string "struct", so your solution does not work unfortunately.

Comment: Ups - thought g:datePicker sends it through as one string.