# reading the value of <g:datePicker>

Tags: grails

how to read the value in the controller submitted in g:datePicker

```
<g:datePicker name="foobar" value="${new Date()}" precision="day" />
```

Thanks

Comment: Where? In controller: params.foobar, on the page - document.getElementById('foobar').val() or jquery like style. Complete your question, please

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534330/reading-the-gdatepicker-value-in-grails-without-using-the-new-objectparams

Comment: I edited the post , yes in the controller. but I tried params.foobar it gave me null although I chossed a value

Comment: in controller action use "println params" and look throw, i think it is enough

Comment: I did that nothing called foobar in params map

Comment: Without sharing your controller and params we can't say what the problem.

Comment: it's the basic controller with out any custom methods

Comment: I can't help you without output of params.

Comment: here is the output of params params : [_action_printAll:Print, action:index, controller:prescriptions] as you see there is no foobar key

Comment: What do you submit? Is datepicker located inside form?

Comment: @baxxabit what a silly mistake the datePicker was outside the form, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your datepicker to the `form` element, then in controller look at params.

also look at similar question

[Reading the g:datePicker-value in Grails without using the "new Object(params)"-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534330/reading-the-gdatepicker-value-in-grails-without-using-the-new-objectparams?rq=1)